# Lorentzian path integral for string theory and causality

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, metric-tensor, causality, wick-rotation

Is the Lorentzian path integral in string theory well defined, as opposed to the usual Euclidian path integral that is commonly used for simplicity? The path integral is roughly

$$\sum_{\mathbf{\mathcal M \in Top}}\int \mathscr DX \mathscr Dg\ e^{i\lambda_{\chi}[\mathcal M ]}\exp{\lbrack i \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-g} g^{ab} \partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X_\mu \rbrack}$$

with a sum over all worldsheet topologies and states for a 2D spacetime with $n$ conformal fields on it.

But most topologies involved in string theory for such a thing involve interpolating topologies between two boundaries. In a Lorentzian context, this would be a Lorentz cobordism, which, for two non-diffeomorphic boundaries, always involve either a loss of time orientability or chronology (I think singularities are also an option but I'm not sure), by a theorem of Geroch.

The only two terms of the sums that would not involve any cobordism will be the open string to open string transition (path integral on the topology $\Bbb R^2$) and the closed string to closed string transition (path integral on the topology $\Bbb R \times S$), as well as any disjoint union of those. All other topological terms will involve some causal pathologies.

Scalar field theories in such contexts are pretty badly divergent (cf [Kay's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9603012) for instance), which makes me wonder if a Lorentzian integral in such a context would converge at all. Is this a problem?

Comment: Usually the integral is defined as a complex continuation of the Euclidean integral. The question of causality is investigated in the results of the theory, not in first principles.